# how to make playwright to type in each character in a variable in to a search bar

Tags: playwright, sys, playwright-python

there is a  website (company website - cant share login) which has a search box containing locations

i was using fill to type in a randomly selected location from a dictionary

playwright fill in the entire location all at once

---

but the website search bar bugs out if u type in the all string at once.

only way to prevent the search bar from bugging out is **type in each char**

(i tried asking website owners to fix the search bar they dont seem interest)

i tired to following code but it keeps bugging out

parts of the code related to the search bar

```
import random
import time
import sys
```

```
random10 = ""
lda_10 = {
    1: "bahria town - overseas A",
    2: "bahria town - awais qarni block",
    3: "bahria town - shaheen block",
    4: "bahria town - shaheen block extension",
    5: "bahria town - Ghouri block",
    6: "bahria town - takbeer block",
    7: "bahria town - Gulbahar Block",
    }

def R_10():
    global random10
    random10 = random.choice(list(lda_10.values()))
    for l in random10:
     sys.stdout.write(l)
     sys.stdout.flush()
     time.sleep(0.2)

page.locator("#location_id_input").fill(random10)
page.locator("(//ul)[8]/li[1]").click
```

i expected the code to type in the chars but it just does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to use [page.type](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-type). It sends the events like a user typing on a keyboard would and you can also set a timeout to simulate a delay like a user would have.

```
await page.type("#location_id_input", random10, {delay: 100});
```

Comment: File "e:\autoplayright.py", line 137, in run
    page.type("#location_id_input", random10, {delay: 100});
                                               ^^^^^
NameError: name 'delay' is not defined

Comment: Sorry, my answer was in typescript for [python](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-page#page-type) it would be
```await page.type("#location_id_input",  random10, delay=100)```